# Ubuntu does not start up automatically

Tags: boot

I loaded ubuntu onto the hard drive and got a message that it was successfully installed. When I try to restart with ubuntu it does not boot up, it does not recognize the ubuntu os, msg shows on screen asking to boot from a cd.

I can use ubuntu from the dvd drive as a "try ubuntu", but will not work otherwise. I've tried several different times adjusting the bios boot sequence.

can you give some other constructive advice on how to get it to boot up automatically from the hard drive?

There are no other programs on the hard drive, about 25gb, it was reformatted, it's an old computer from about 2002, Pentium 4, w/3gb ram.

give detailed info., not that tech savy.

thanks.

Comment: do you see "grub" when you start the computer? grub is a purple screen

Answer (score 0):

On the Ubuntu CD if I remember correctly there is an option to boot into the first hard drive the loader finds. Have you tried that? If that works for you then likely GRUB (bootloader to start OS's, after the bios as decided to boot from the first drive it will then hand over selecting an OS to GRUB) was installed wrong, or to the wrong location. There are many pages under the Ubuntu help website that can explain how to do this better than I can. Just Google 'reinstall grub ubuntu' the ones that are 'help.ubuntu.com' are the ones you want.

If that doesn't work I'd recommend just trying to reinstall again, and if possible select the option to install GRUB to the MBR (Master Boot Record, basically a list of OS's on the hard drive), instead of to the first partition as it sometimes does.